# Copying data from unbootable Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Two days ago I turned on my Mac to find out that it doesn't boot anymore. I tried everything, Safe Boot, NVRAM reset, repair disk from recovery mode everything; but, no luck.  So, I finally decided to reinstall Yosemite.

But before that I want to copy some files from the hard disk. So what should I do?

Comment: Reinstalling Yosemite doesn't wipe your drive, unless you meant you're planning to format the drive first.

Comment: I'm going to do a clean install

Answer (score 2):

If you have another computer that can support target disk mode, simply boot with T held and connect per your MacBook (usb or thunderbolt or FireWire are all possible target disk mode). Your Mac is now a hard drive to copy / recover the data.

If not, Assuming you do not have a current Time Machine Backup then...

If you can boot to the **Recovery HD**, then attach an external USB/FireWire/Thunderbolt drive (whichever works for you since you didn't state what Mac you have, and boot to **Recovery HD** and then use **Disk Utility** to make a **Disk Image** of your **Home Folder** to the external drive.  Or a Disk Image of whatever Folders you want to save.

In **Disk Utility** click, **File > New > Disk Image from Folder...**

In the **Select Folder to Image** dialog box navigate to the target location, e.g. `/Macintosh HD/Users/$USER` and select the **Folder**, then click the **Image** button.

In the **New Image from Folder** dialog box, name the image and then navigate to the external target location to be saved and then click the **Save** button.

In this example, you now have a disk image of your Home folder on an external drive and can copy your User Data back from that image after you clean install the OS.